# how to clear all fields including readonly fields in handsontable

Tags: javascript, handsontable

Iam trying to filter my handsontable based on some criteria. So i would like to reload handsontable based on filter value before that i tried to clear all fields.

All fields gets cleared except **readonly** fields.

Ihave used the following line of code to clear all fields.

```
      $("#exampleid").handsontable('clear');
```

Please help me to do the same.

Thank You!

Comment: How many readonly fields do you have?

Comment: i have 4 readonly fields....

Answer (score 0):

I think in handsontable once you mark particular field you can't clear it. 
In your case I would suggest to first mark these fields as `readOnly: false` and then perform your clear operation.
I know this is something is not solution when you have many read only fields.

If you want to know about more methods to manipulate data visit Alter/Set section of [this](https://github.com/handsontable/jquery-handsontable/wiki/Methods) link